# Intel 10Gbps NIC not working within Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, 10gbethernet, sfp, solaris-11

I'm working within Solaris 11.1 on hardware that is on the Solaris 11 HCL.  My Intel X520-DA2 is failing to initialize.

> Jun 14 03:11:32 ATM-Front-End-1 ixgbe: [ID 611667 kern.warning] WARNING: ixgbe1: Failed to initialize adapter

Here is the output of some ixgbe commands:

*root@XXXXXX:~# modinfo | grep ixgbe*

*224 fffffffff823a000 31c10 135 1 ixgbe (Intel 10Gb Ethernet)*

*root@XXXX:~# grep ixgbe /etc/path_to_inst*

*"/pci@0,0/pci8086,340a@3/pci8086,3@0" 0 "ixgbe"*

*"/pci@0,0/pci8086,340a@3/pci8086,3@0,1" 1 "ixgbe"*

*"/pci@0,0/pci8086,340c@5/pci8086,3@0" 2 "ixgbe"*

*"/pci@0,0/pci8086,340c@5/pci8086,3@0,1" 3 "ixgbe"*

I installed Windows on the same server (to a different HDD) to verify the card works.  I am also using an Intel branded and Intel approved SFP Twinnax module/cable.

Does anyone have experience with this issue?  Oracle has been useless thus far.

Comment: For what is worth I tried using Solaris 10 2 years ago, mostly because the native, more mature support for zfs and its ability to cache drives. Ended up totally discarding this path because even though 10Gbe Intel card worked it would break down the moment I sent more than 100Mbits of traffic. All networking stopped working when I tried to server more than that. Tried increasing interrupt limits, buffers and stuff, posted on solaris forums and in the end just shoved the idea of using Solaris in the trash bin.. It may even been 11, dont remember, their own forums were totally unhelpful also.

Comment: Fun fact, my card had the same chipset used in their own solaris server hardware ;) Exactly the same.